# setActualSize() with Label components confusion

Tags: apache-flex

If you are extending UIComponent and you add a Label component to your custom component it seems you have to use setActualSize() in order for your label to appear. The problem is I don't know what size the label is going to be as it depends on the length of the text and the font size. Sometimes this works:

```
label.setActualSize(label.getExplicitOrMeasuredWidth(),
    label.getExplicitOrMeasuredHeight())
```

but not always. I'm not sure of the reason for this.

What's the best way to set a label to its actual size?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you call `setActualSize()` on the Label in your UIComponent's `updateDisplayList()` function. That's where it's supposed to happen. If you call it anywhere else in the validation cycle, the child Label may not have finished measurement.